# dbms_output for systimestamp in milliseconds

Tags: oracle

My target is to dbms_output the time difference in milliseconds inside the pl/sql block as shown in the code. Now, the dbms_output result is 0 which is not true. I know I have to apply some conversion functions in order to get the correct time difference but I am unable to solve it. Can any one help me on this? I really appreciate for the help!

```
create table city
(cityid numeric(10),
cityname varchar2(20),
cityregion VARCHAR(20),
citypopulation INT,
constraint city_pk primary key (cityid));

declare
c_id  number := 0 ;
c_name varchar2(30) ;
c_region varchar2(30);
c_pop number;
cityid_copy city.cityid%TYPE;
time_before timestamp;
time_after timestamp;
begin
while (c_id <= 30000000)
loop
c_name    := 'City' || c_id;
c_region  := 'Region' || c_id;
c_pop     := c_id + 500;

insert into city
(cityid,cityname,cityregion,citypopulation)
values(c_id,c_name,c_region,c_pop);
c_id := c_id +1;
end loop;
time_before := systimestamp;
select cityid into cityid_copy from city
where cityid = 3000000;
time_after := systimestamp;
dbms_output.put_line((time_after)-(time_before));
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean "result is 0"?  Subtracting two timestamps returns an interval so you should see something like `+000000000 00:00:00.009000000` if the query took 9 milliseconds.  If you mean that the interval is all 0's are you sure that the query takes more than a millisecond?

Comment: Yes, the query actually takes like 4 seconds when I do select cityid from city 
where cityid = 3000000 outside the block.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The query should be doing a very quick read of the right-most leaf block in the primary key index to get the single row you're interested in.  That shouldn't take anywhere close to 4 seconds.  If statistics on your table aren't accurate and the query does a full table scan of a 30 million row table, I'd expect it to take rather more than 4 seconds.

Comment: So now I just dropped and created the table again and then inserted 30000 recorders. I also added dbms_lock.sleep(0.1); to the code. The time is still zero. But when I do select cityid from city
where cityid = 30000 outside the code, it took 1 second.

Comment: Are you saying that `dbms_output` is printing a single 0?  Or an interval of all 0's `+000000000 00:00:00.000000000`?  What happens if you print out the `systimestamp` before and after the query?  On my laptop, with 30,000 rows, the query generally runs in less than a millisecond (though occasionally it clocks 1 or 2 milliseconds).  If I put the `dbms_lock.sleep` call between the two `systimestamp` calls, I generally see 100 milliseconds with occasional 101 or 102 millisecond runs.

Comment: The time before and after the querying looks the same for the 30, 000 records. But When I do the query outside the plsql code, it takes 1 second.                                                                                                              26-JUL-15 09.28.53.640000 PM
26-JUL-15 09.28.53.640000 PM
+000000000 00:00:00.000000000.

Comment: And that's with the `dbms_lock.sleep(0.1)` after `time_before` is set and before `time_after` is set?  Or without the `dbms_lock` call?  That's what I'd expect without the `dbms_lock` call-- the query takes less than a millisecond.

Comment: So the time registered after the correction is 26-JUL-15 10.20.25.609000 PM
26-JUL-15 10.20.25.828000 PM. And this is for 3 million records. What exactly did the dbms_lock.sleep procedure did to it?

Comment: `dbms_lock.sleep(0.1)` just causes the procedure to pause for a tenth of a second (100 milliseconds).

Comment: So in my case, there was a pause for 200 milliseconds and then the time_after was recorded. But what I want to figure out is that how long is it taking to do the select into statement in my code. I want to test this by increasing the rows inserted. What was the relevance of me including the dbms_lock.sleep in the code?

Comment: Including the `dbms_lock.sleep` forces the elapsed time to be large enough to be measurable.  If the table has only 30,000 rows, it is unlikely that it would take more than a millisecond to run your query.  When the table had 3 million rows, it apparently took roughly 117 milliseconds (828 - 609 - 100).  When there was a 217 ms difference between `start_time` and `end_time`, what did your existing `dbms_output` call print out?  Was the interval that was displayed 217 ms?  Or was it still all 0's?

Comment: The difference was 219 which is (828-609). But shouldn't you subtract 200 instead of 100? because the code was paused twice before time_after was registered? time_before := systimestamp;
dbms_lock.sleep(0.1);
select cityid into cityid_copy from city
where cityid = 30000;
dbms_lock.sleep(0.1);
time_after := systimestamp; And now I dropped the table and created it again. Inserted 30, 000 rows but the time difference is the same 218 milliseconds. Shouldn't it be less now comparing 30, 000 and 3,000,000 records?

Comment: I was assuming that you had just one call.  If you have two `dbms_lock.sleep` calls then, yes, you'd need to subtract 200 ms.  I wouldn't generally expect the performance of a single-row read from an index to differ much whether the table had 30,000 rows or 3,000,000 rows particularly if all the index blocks you need to read are already cached.  If your system gave you microsecond (or nanosecond) precision or if you averaged enough runs, you might see a very small difference between the two depending on the height of the index in both cases.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I always drop the table so that there is no cached data to read from. But thank you so much for your precious time and I really appreciate the help. Good day sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is faster than the operating system timestamp precision.  On many operating systems `SYSTIMESTAMP` is only precise to thousandths of a second.

```
SQL> select to_char(systimestamp, 'FF9') fractional_seconds from dual;

FRACTIONA
---------
711000000

SQL> select to_char(systimestamp, 'FF9') fractional_seconds from dual;

FRACTIONA
---------
715000000

SQL> select to_char(systimestamp, 'FF9') fractional_seconds from dual;

FRACTIONA
---------
718000000
```

If you add `dbms_lock.sleep(0.1);` to the code the result will not be zero anymore.

As far as I know there is no workaround to this issue.  There's no way to measure something that takes less than one thousandth of a second on these platforms.  Although if that's really all the time it takes then it probably doesn't need to be measured anyway.